# HttpClient seems to be causing my app to slowdown every ~3 minutes while freeing up a ton of memory

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, dotnet-httpclient

So basically I am running a program which is able to send up to 7,000 HTTP requests every second in average, 24/7, in order to detect last changes on a website as quickly as possible.

However, every 2.5 to 3 minutes in average, my program slowdowns for around 10-15 seconds and goes from ~7K rq/s to less than 1000.

Here are logs from my program, where you can see the amount of requests it sends every second:
https://pastebin.com/029VLxZG

When scrolling down through the logs, you can see it goes slower every ~3 minutes. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUqmr.jpg

At first I thought it was my server's ethernet connection going in a temporary "restricted" mode, and I even tried contacting my host about it. But then I ran 2 instances of my program simulteanously just to see what would happen and I noticed that, even though the issue (downtime) was happening on both, it wasn't always happening at the same time (depending on when the program was started, if you get what I mean), which meant the problem wasn't coming from the internet connection, but my program itself.

I investigated a little bit more, and found out that as soon as my program goes from ~7K rq/s to ~700, a lot of RAM is being freed up on my server.

I have taken 2 screenshots of the consecutive seconds before and once the downtime occurs (including RAM metrics), to compare, and you can view them here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9BWB.jpg (please note that I was using less threads here, which is why the average "normal" speed is ~2K rq/s instead of ~7K as mentioned before)

If you'd like to see more of it, here is the full record of the issue, in a video which lasts about 40 seconds: https://i.imgur.com/z27FlVP.mp4 - As you can see, after the RAM is freed up, its usage slowly goes up again, before the same process repeats every ~3 minutes.

For more context, here is the method I am using to send the HTTP requests (it is being called from a lot of threads concurrently, as my app is multi-threaded in order to be super fast):

```cs
public static async Task<bool> HasChangedAsync(string endpoint, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    const string baseAddress = "https://example.com/";

    string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(baseAddress + endpoint);

    return response.Contains("example");
}
```

One thing I did is I tried replacing the whole method by `await Task.Delay(25)` then `return false`, and that fixed the issue, RAM usage was barely increasing.

This lead me to believe the issue is `HttpClient` / my HTTP requests, and even though I tried replacing the `GetStringAsync` method by `GetAsync` using both a `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` (and disposing them with `using`), the behavior ended up being the exact same.

So here I am, desperate for a fix, and without enough knowledge about memory, garbage collector etc (if that's even needed here) to be able to fix this myself.

Please, Stack Overflow, do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your `GetStringAsync` is most likely generating large strings which will end up in Large Object Heap. At your rate of requests, no doubt your system will do heaps of full GCs which will slow down your entire system.

Comment: Hello @JohanP and thanks a lot for your answer. That's what I was thinking as well. The web page response contains more than 5K characters and I guess once I retrieve it to store it in my `response` string variable it never gets removed from memory after that. What would be a good way to make this happen, though? I don't think setting my `string response` variable to `null` will work and I do not have any other idea. And is that even the issue?

Comment: An other (maybe stupid) question: Could the `baseAddress + endpoint` string I'm creating and passing as a parameter to the `GetStringAsync` method also be filling my RAM without ever being removed from it? Specifying "(maybe stupid)" because I really don't have much knowledge about how memory, GC etc works so it might sound like a beginner question

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to stream the response and then use chunks of it to find what your are looking for. An example implementation could be something as follows:

```cs
using var response = await Client.GetAsync(BaseUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
await using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string line = null;
while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
{
    if(line.Contains("example"))// do whatever
}
```

Comment: Still generating a lot of strings, although they would be small and in GC Gen0. An even more efficient implementation would hold a `byte[]` buffer and read a chunk at a time, checking for the equivalent bytes as it goes. Obviously more complex because of possible split matches, therefore possibly overkill

Comment: Hey Johan, thanks for your answer. I have tried it, however the RAM usage remains about the same, and the exact same issue is still [there](https://i.imgur.com/Pqbk3dE.jpg) . It doesn't look like replacing my code with yours made any difference, sadly. Maybe buying a server with more RAM (I currently have only 4 GB) might help?

Comment: Update: I tried with a 6 GB server end even though the task manager was continuously showing "2.5 GB available" the same problem happened, so I guess it will even happen on a server with 16, 32 or even 64 GB of RAM. I'm really desperate for a fix and would even tip someone a good amount of money in cryptocurrency to help me, as this issue is strongly impacting my business.

Comment: @Matt How are you instantiating `HttpClient`?

Comment: @JohanP I instantiate multiple `HttpClient`s on my program launch, 1 per proxy (I have 9,000 proxies so 9,000 `HttpClient`s are being instantiated when my program launches), then reuse them forever. Also, as I mentioned in my original post: One thing I did is I tried replacing the whole method by `await Task.Delay(25)` then `return false`, and that fixed the issue, RAM usage was barely increasing. Therefore I don't think the problem is related to how I instantiate my `HttpClient`s, unless you have a reason to believe so?

Comment: Could you try just using `using var response = await Client.GetAsync(BaseUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
await using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();` and then return `false` to check if request per second drop is due to strings or due to making connections

Comment: @JohanP Thanks for your idea. I have tried replacing my current method with what you proposed, however the issue remained present. I then tried to remove the `await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();` part (leaving only the `await GetAsync(...); return false;` code) but that didn't fix it neither. I even tried replacing the URL I'm calling by a `const string` so that there's no string generation there, but that didn't seem to be the issue neither. So there is only one culprit left, and it is `using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(...);`. What can I do from now on?

Comment: TLDR: The issue lies in the HTTP request.

Comment: @Matt I did a basic benchmark and doing a single http request allocates roughly 35KB of memory. If you are doing 7000 a second, just the http calls will generate around 240MB a second! That is a bunch of work. You can try and muck around with the GC mode, i.e. workstation vs server and see if it makes a difference for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc